# R. Join with duplicates only once

Tags: r, join, merge

I need help to join two data frames by one key with duplicates.
I want to merge only once for each duplicate, and I can't do it with `dplyr::left_join`.

Example:

```
    ds1 <- data.frame(
      id = c(1,1,1,2,2),
      V2 = c(5,6,7,5,8)
      )
    ds2<-data.frame(
      id=c(1,2),
      Value=c(56,98)
      )
    ds3<-left_join(ds1, ds2, by="id")
```

In this case I have:

```
# id V2 Value
1  1  5    56
2  1  6    56
3  1  7    56
4  2  5    98
5  2  8    98
```

But I need:

```
# id V2 Value
1  1  5    56
2  1  6    
3  1  7    
4  2  5    98
5  2  8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep your code and just add this:

```
ds3$Value[duplicated(ds3[c("Value","id")])] <- NA
#   id V2 Value
# 1  1  5    56
# 2  1  6    NA
# 3  1  7    NA
# 4  2  5    98
# 5  2  8    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea using `slice`, `left_join`, and then `full_join`.

```
ds3 <- ds1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  left_join(ds2, by = "id") %>%
  full_join(ds1, by = c("id", "V2")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(id, V2)
ds3
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#     id    V2 Value
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    1.    5.   56.
# 2    1.    6.   NA 
# 3    1.    7.   NA 
# 4    2.    5.   98.
# 5    2.    8.   NA
```